# logic in fit() and predict() method for regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression

Can anyone please explain me the concept of `fit()` and `predict()` used in machine learning algorithms.

```
fit()- used to fit the data.
     output- LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
```

Query1 = what is the back end calculation for fit. On what basis do we get the above output after calling `fit()` method.

`predict()` - used to predict the data.

Query2 = what is the back end calculation used here.

These are some basic conceptual understanding that I need. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Look up "econometrics", "least squares" and "maximum likelihood"

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* issues and *not* a tutorial service. Plus, questions about the "concept" and the "backend calculation" are arguably both too broad and rather vague - in any case off-topic here...

Answer (score -1):

I learned logistic regression (machine learning) by reading a very interesting book that gives you some basics but also gives you difficult algorithms. You can find the code examples at : https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/tree/master/code at chapter 3 you will find logistic regression but not the algorithm.
Anyway, the fit() method is used to adapt the data at the algorithm, it's just for it and as far as i know there's not an algorithm, it's just to an "organization" purpose. The predict() method in logistic regression uses the sigmoid function and logarithmic expression. 
Now i do not remember the algorithms calculations (sorry) but i can get in a few ours.

Comment: "*the fit() method is just for it and as far as i know there's not an algorithm*" is both wrong (here is where the **essence** of *all* algorithms lies) and arguably not an answer; additionally, please refrain from answering blatantly off-topic questions, as suggested in the community guidelines - see [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions) and [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: @desertnaut, didn't know about these. Thanks for pointing it out. I'm deleting my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In Machine Learning you want to make a model of a real-world concept. For example, there's a good chance there is a correlation between the growth of a plant and the amount of water it gets. fit() will try to fit this correlation in a mathematical formula (= the model, a simplification of the real-world concept).
Fitting means that the algorithm will try to repeatedly adjust it's estimate, based on the error it had in in his previous guess.

Note sure what you mean with your second question, but if you're asking how Linear Regression works, you can check-out wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression
It gives a very good explanation of the basic concept.

Keep in mind however, that LinearRegression() will do a multi-variable linear regression, so it only a linear relationship in de nD plane, not in 2D.

Comment: "*Not sure what you mean, but see Wikipedia for an explanation*" is arguably not an answer; please refer to my comment in the other answer regarding answering off-topic questions.